# Python set __contains__ is not finding objects contained in the set

Tags: python, set, contains

(python 3.7.1 on linux)

I am observing some strange behavior storing user-defined objects in a set.  The objects are highly complex so a minimal example is not in the cards-- but I am hoping the observed behavior will elicit an explanation from someone wiser than myself.  Here it is:

```
>>> from mycode import MyObject
>>> a = MyObject(*args1)
>>> b = MyObject(*args2)
>>> a == b
False
>>> z = {a, b}
>>> len(z)
2
>>> a in z
False
```

My understanding was that an object is "in" a set if (1) its hash matches the hash of an object in the set and (2) it equals that object.  But those expectations are violated here:

```
>>> [hash(t) for t in z]
[1013724486348463466, -1852733432963649245]
>>> hash(a)
1013724486348463466
>>> [(hash(t) == hash(a), t == a) for t in z]
[(True, True), (False, False)]
>>> [t is a for t in z]
[True, False]
```

And the strangest (syntactically) of all:

```
>>> [t in z for t in z]
[False, False]
```

What might be up with `MyObject` to cause it to behave this way?  To recap: it has a sane `__hash__` and `__eq__` function, `set` is just a stock python set.

Here they are specifically:

```
class MyObject(object):
    ...
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.link)

        def __eq__(self, other):
            """
            two entities are equal if their types, origins, and external references are the same.
            internal refs do not need to be equal; reference entities do not need to be equal
            :return:
            """
            if other is None:
                return False
            try:
                is_eq = (self.external_ref == other.external_ref
                         and self.origin == other.origin
                         and self.entity_type == other.entity_type)
            except AttributeError:
                is_eq = False
            return is_eq
```

All of those properties are defined on these objects. As demonstrated above, `a == t` evaluates to `True` for one of the objects in the set.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I would say that you get `except AttributeError` because one of the members isn't defined. Can you post the code for your object? try to print a message when `AttributeError` is reached

Comment: Would there be something fishy going on in the comparison of `self.external_ref` etc?

Comment: You're using `__eq__`, but I think to get the desired behavior you need to use `__contains__`.

Comment: I bet you mutated objects after adding them to the set.

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense that `__hash__` and `__eq__` are looking at completely disjoint sets of attributes.

Comment: nope: `>>> a in z
False` in the first example

Comment: The object is embarrassingly complex... it can be viewed here: https://github.com/bkuczenski/lca-tools/blob/master/antelope_catalog/foreground/fragments.py (inheriting from here: https://github.com/bkuczenski/lca-tools/blob/master/lcatools/entities/entities.py)

Comment: but even if hash is bogus, that doesn't prevent set from working. We need a [mcve]. Your class is too big? reduce it for a [mcve]

Comment: @user2357112 `object.link` is `'/'.join([object.origin, object.external_ref])`

Comment: @user2357112 i think you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mutating the objects after adding them to the set.  The hash function as defined was not static.